# execute php app/console doctrine:schema:update from controller symfony 2

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I want to execute this  command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

from the controles without use `exec` php function,

Any comment will be use full to me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are looking [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/console.html), on the bottom there is an example of how to execute a command from within symfony code.

Please also mind the note on the end saying that it might not be a good idea to use a command within your code.

As said, the following code should be used with care. I wouldn't use it for the reasons statet in the symfony doc, but it works.

When using the following code within your controller, you are able to execute a command:

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

$options = array('command' => 'list');
$application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
```

If you need the output, you have to either use an existing class implementing OutputInterface or create your own depending on your needs.

Comment: @JERC it refers to not using a command from within code that isn't executed on the command line. If you're intending to call it from within your app, consider refactoring the code out to a separate class/service and then adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: True, but you can modify it to use it in a Controller. I will update my answer!

Comment: Thanks it works, but to do it like a service how I can do this, sorry but I'm begginer in symfony 2. Thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to every one,

I used this code

```
            $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
            $application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
            $application->setAutoExit(false);
            //Create de Schema 
            $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',"--force" => true);
            $application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
            //Loading Fixtures
            $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:fixtures:load',"--append" => true);
            $application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
```

and in this [link](http://blog.sznapka.pl/fully-isolated-tests-in-symfony2/), there are some information maybe will be usefull for others

Thanks!!!

Comment: Any idea on how to make entities discoverable without the need to clear the cache ?